# Sql запрос работает в pma но не работает в php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

может кто сталкивался?

```
$prod_get_attr = "SELECT oca.product_id, pr.price, pr.image, pd.name 
FROM oc_product_attribute AS oca LEFT JOIN oc_product AS pr ON pr.product_id = oca.product_id 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description AS pd ON pd.product_id = oca.product_id 
WHERE text IN ('" . $get_material_item . "') AND oca.product_id IN (SELECT oca2.product_id FROM oc_product_attribute AS oca2 
WHERE text IN ('" . $get_ves_item . "')) GROUP BY oca.product_id"; 
                             $query_prod_get_attr = mysqli_query($dbh, $prod_get_attr);
                             var_dump($query_prod_get_attr);
```

Данный скрипт работает в pma если ввести значения вручную (не переменными), переношу в скрипт и получаю не массив значений а bool(false), подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так
WHERE text IN ({$get_material_item}) AND oca.product_id IN (SELECT oca2.product_id FROM oc_product_attribute AS oca2
WHERE text IN ({$get_ves_item})) GROUP BY oca.product_id";

Comment: Та же самая ошибка...

Comment: В $get_material_item и  $get_ves_item точно приходят значения ?

Comment: Да, тоже думал дело в этом, но вывожу их и все ок

Comment: С коннетом к базе все ок?

Comment: Да, другие запросы выполняются

Comment: ```echo mysqli_error($dbh); ``` Получил ```Unknown column 'Серебро' in 'where clause'bool(false)```

Comment: 'Серебро' это $get_material_item